# Secure a webservice call in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection

I am already aware of HTTPS calls but i wanted to know if there is some other way as well to secure data over network or should we have to always rely on HTTPS calls?

I will be calling a SOAP based web service from my objective C code using NSURLConnection class. My concern is how can i send the data in a secure manner over the network few items which i know are

- Using public and private keys
- Using SSL

Apart from this technique is there any other way in which we can secure the data that we send over the network.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to use https.

Comment: Its the function of `HTTPS` to provide *transport security*, what's wrong with using that?

Comment: Ya i know that i am already doing it. My question is can we encrypt the data that we are sending to the server and then send it also whats apart from HTTPS is that the only thing that we have or do we have something else?

What if the HTTPS function fails ? OR assume that it has failed then what do we do to save the data

Comment: HTTPS is considered reliable enough that it is what's used for submitting credit card details over the internet- is what your sending more sensitive that data of that type?  If NSURLConnection cannot establish an HTTPS connection, then it won't.  If there is a problem with the connection such as an expired server certificate/name mismatch then it will throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it, and it largely depends on what type of traffic you want to send over the link, and what's at the other end receiving it. However, it is highly likely that whichever method you use, and whatever traffic you send, it'll be SSL doing the encryption.

Some background: HTTPS is just a shorthand for plain old HTTP transmitted over an SSL encrypted connection, so if you use HTTPS, you're using SSL to encrypt HTTP traffic. SSL is the cryptographic code you need to do the encryption/decryption, HTTP is the protocol (language) that web servers speak, as opposed to FTP, Telnet, SMTP, and other Internet protocols, which SSL can also encrypt.  SSL  uses public and private keys as part of its encryption: public key cryptography is just a technique SSL uses to secure your connection.

Usually what the client does is dictated by what the server supports. It would be highly unusual for a web service not to be built on HTTP these days, and also, but slightly less, unusual for it not to support HTTPS.

Unless there's a really good reason not to, you should use HTTPS.